# How do I get the user's email in the user profile template?

Tags: 7, users

I am trying to customize the user-profile.tpl.php file.

I can access the all custom fields using `$user_profile['field_fieldname']`, and I can even access the user picture using `$user_profile['user_picture']`, but I don't know how to get the user email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by following way.

```
$account = menu_get_object('user');
$mail = $account->mail;
```

Answer (score 1):

The email field is part of the $user variable.  For the currently logged in user, you can get to it via:

```
global $user;
$user_email=$user->mail;
```

and a quick:

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($user,true) . '</pre>');
```

will show you all sorts of information that is available.

If you need it for a different user, you need to grab the `$node->uid` from the node you are looking at and then do a `user_load($node->uid)` to get to the info...

Comment: I tried this it didn't work.

Comment: The user profile template file is not associated with any node.

Answer (score 0):

You do know that Users are fieldable now, so you can add whatever CCK fields you want, like phone number, links, e-mail, etc.  Each it's own field type.  There's no need to get messy in your template files to customize the user profiles.

Comment: Yah i know that but I don't want to use custom field for email.

Comment: Rupesh Pawar just wants to use the email address that is associated with the user object. The user object used by Drupal already contains a property for that, without the need of a CCK field.